# Titanium issue with Facebook Login button and Navigation group

Tags: facebook, navigation, titanium

I have a navigation group that is used for login. If the user is logged in succesfully tha app closes the navigation group (with navGroup.close which I assume that this is destroyed) and create a tab group. When the user logged out the tabgroup is closed and the navigation group is created again. The issue is the the facebook login button(which is on navigation group) is works ok the 1st time that the navgroup is created but the second time is executed the 'login' listener 2 times and the 3d time 3 times and so on.
Here is a simplified code that generate this bug:

app.js

```
Ti.App.Properties.setString("fbAccess","login");

Ti.Facebook.appid = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
Ti.Facebook.permissions = ['publish_stream','offline_access','email'];
//Ti.Facebook.forceDialogAuth = false;
Ti.include('preLogin.js');
```

loginFBC.js

```
Ti.Facebook.addEventListener('login', function(e) {

   Ti.API.info("inside login"); 

   if ((e.success) && (Ti.App.Properties.getString("fbAccess")=="login")) {
                        Ti.API.info("inside if");   

                     navGroup.close();
                     Ti.include('preLogin.js');
                       }});
```

preLogin.js

```
var buttonLoginFB = Titanium.UI.createButton({
     top: "90%",
     width: "70%",
     height: "12%"});

var preLoginWin = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    titleImage:'/icons/logoForBar.png',     
    title:"Back",
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    barColor:'00aeef',
   });
var buttonLogin = Titanium.UI.createButton({
     title: 'Login',
     top: "30%",
     width: "70%",
     height: "12%",
     opacity:1
    });

var buttonRegister = Titanium.UI.createButton({
     title: 'Register',
     top: "60%",
     width: "70%",
     height: "12%",
     opacity:1

    });




    var navGroup = Ti.UI.iPhone.createNavigationGroup({
                    window:preLoginWin
    });

    preLoginWin.add(buttonLogin,buttonRegister,buttonLoginFB);

    var main = Ti.UI.createWindow();

    main.add(navGroup); 
    main.open();

Ti.include('/loginFBC.js');
//include the preLoginC.js that holds the code for the buttons listeners
Ti.include('/preLoginC.js');
```

and the preLoginC.js

```
buttonLoginFB.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

Ti.API.info("button");

Ti.Facebook.logout();
Ti.Facebook.appid = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
Ti.Facebook.permissions = ['publish_stream','offline_access','email'];
//Ti.Facebook.forceDialogAuth = false;
Ti.Facebook.authorize();


});
```

Comment: u find the solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

You really should reconsider how your laying out your application, first of all, everything you have defined is in the global javascript namespace, this is an extremely bad idea : refer to [this talk on best practices for Javascript with Titanium.](http://player.vimeo.com/video/29754525?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&color=9a0707&autoplay=1)

The second thing you should probably not be doing is having a navigation group with a tab bar.  Instead why not just open a new window with a one-off modal like this?

```
var modalWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({...formatting here...});
modalWindow.open({modal : true});
```

Bad practice aside, the reason your seeing multiple facebook windows popup is because you have added multiple event listeners to the  *buttonLoginFB* button. This is happening because you are including *preLogin.js* when you authorize Facebook, which in turn includes *preLoginC.js* which is adding your listener.

To fix this, you need to change your general architecture based on Titanium best practices.  Move your UI elements into a safer namespace, and do not include Javascript files inside of event listeners, this will ALWAYS cause problems.

Hope this helps!